# Segmentation fault in LCA implementation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
/*  
if node in the first section then P[node]=1  
if node in the beginning of some section then P[node]=T[node]  
if none then P[node]=P[T[node]]  
*/
#define SIZE 102
int T[SIZE];//the father of node i in the tree
int L[SIZE];//level of the node i
int P[SIZE];//lowest ancestor of the node from the prev. section
//pre-process p using DFS
int N;
int nr;//sqrt(H)
list<int>Child[SIZE];
list<int>::iterator it;

 void dfs(int node)
    {
        if(L[node]<nr)
            P[node]=1;
            else
                {
                    if(L[node]%nr==0)//SEG-FAULT here node=6316144
                         P[node]=T[node];
                         else
                             P[node]=P[T[node]];
                 }
            //for each son k of node
         for(it=Child[node].begin();it!=Child[node].end();it++)
              {
                 dfs(*it);
              }
    }

//here's the code to initialize L and nr
int initialize()
  {
    //initialize the L array and the nr value by finding out value of H
    int root,i;
    for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
      {
        if(T[i]==-1)
          {
            root=i;
            break;
          }
      }
    queue<int>Q;
    queue<int>t;
    t.push(root);
    int s,l=0;//nodes at the same level


    //process all the nodes in the Q at this moment
     while(!t.empty())        
     {
       while(!t.empty())
        {
            s=t.front();
            t.pop();

            L[s]=l;
            Q.push(s);
        }   
        while(!Q.empty())
        {
           s=Q.front();
           Q.pop();
           for(it=Child[s].begin();it!=Child[s].end();it++)//children of node s
             t.push(*it);
        }
        l++;
     }  



    int height=l;
    nr=sqrt(height);
    return root;
}

//here's the code to obtain the tree
void getTree()
{
   // printf("\nHow many nodes?");
     scanf("%d",&N);
   //printf("\nNow enter the tree as parent #children children");
     int i,n,p,j,c;
     for(i=0;i<=N;i++)
         T[i]=-1;//all the nodes do not have parents
     for(i=0;i<N;i++)
       {
         scanf("%d%d",&p,&n);
           for(j=0;j<n;j++)
             {
               scanf("%d",&c);
               Child[p].push_back(c);//child is pushed in the correct parent's list
               T[c]=p;//parent is updated
             }
       }
 }
```

The above is a simple code to populate the P array for solving LCA (Lowest Common Ancestor) problem(from topcoder article).
nr=sqrt(H)(evaluated using another function).
The global array of lists Child contains the index of the children of node.Some of the lists are empty if the nodes are leaves.
The L array contains the levels of the nodes(0 based )initialized using BFS(this is correct).
The problem is whenever the input is given and dfs(r)(the root)is called segmentation fault happens and value of node in the line indicated is shown as 6316144. 
I just cannot understand what has gone wrong...

Comment: Try running it through valgrind if you can.

Comment: Thanks...tried using gdb

Comment: So if you've used gdb you must have some idea how `node` got to be 6316144. Since node is not assigned to in that function I'm damned if I know. Could be some memory corruption somewhere. Really impossible to tell with the code posted.

Comment: nr is not zero.L is also properly initialized but node gets out of bounds for L.(How?)

Comment: You should clear up your code and paste the complete source. What is L? P? Am I supposed to know the LCA problem from topcoder? IMHO, I think questions should be as clear and complete as possible.

Comment: I don't know where that code came from, and I don't care much: global variables kill kittens. I will not take time to debug such filth, better things to do, and I advise you not to either: rewrite it properly so that each function may be analyzed in isolation, and then we can start analyzing.